# What does background-attachment exactly do?

Tags: html, css, frontend, background-attachment

I was thinking when we write `background: inherit;` it should take all of parent properties exactly and according to it, the background of child element should be reproduced,right?

But today when I worked with background-attachment I faced with a strange result, It seems when we use `background-attachment: fixed;` there is no further inheritance:

```css
body{
  background-image: url('https://helpx.adobe.com/content/dam/help/en/stock/how-to/visual-reverse-image-search/jcr_content/main-pars/image/visual-reverse-image-search-v2_intro.jpg ');
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

#first{
  margin:80px 160px;
  background: inherit;
  border: dotted;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="first"></div>
```

As you can see, the result of above code seems to be equivalent with `#first{ background:transparent; ...}`.

Can anyone explain why this happens with `background-attachment: fixed;`? I searched through Internet but I couldn't find my answer, almost all of the websites just give me the same below irrational explanation:

> The background-attachment property specifies whether the background
> image should scroll or be fixed (will not scroll with the rest of the
> page):

Comment: no, it is inherited just fine. It just happens that you use it in a way that has no visual effect since you *hide* the effect by using the background in two nested divs. Try adding the background only to the div and not the body and you will understand.

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli, Thank you, it was very good to add background to the div and not body:)
can you write your comment in form of an answer? then I accept it and close the question.

Comment: this is all the trick of background-attachment:fixed: Use the same background in different elements and make it look like only one.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Exactly and it is so useful.

Answer (score 0):

Background Attachment sets the property whether a background image scrolls with the rest of the page or is fixed. **It's like Relative Position with Image**